# How to check if I am in Print Preview in Word Application in version 2010,2013,2016 && 2019

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-automation

I am trying to check if I am in print preview(ctrl+P) in two ways, but none of them works on the above versions of office.

The function that I get the active Word appalication object is:

```
using WordApi = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public static WordApi.Application getActiveObject()
        {
            WordApi.Application ap;
            try 
            {
                ap = (WordApi.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ap = null; // this is important
            }
            return ap;
        }
```

```
//block1
public static bool printPreview()
        {
            bool result = false;
            WordApi.Application ap = getActiveObject();
            try
            {
                if (ap.ActiveWindow.View.Type == WordApi.WdViewType.wdPrintPreview) //focus here-works on Office 7
                {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MyLogger.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ap != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ap);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

or

```
//block 2
public static bool printPreview()
        {
            bool result = false;
            WordApi.Application ap = getActiveObject();
            try
            {
                if (ap.PrintPreview())
                {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MyLogger.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ap != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ap);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Is should work in both ways and especially the block 1 but it doesn't. It only works on office 7. Any ideas?

Comment: `ap.PrintPreview` works for me. Does the `catch` block kick in with an error? How `getActiveObject` defined in your project? This does not appear to be the .NET method as it's completely missing the necessary parameters, so we have no idea what it's doing and whether `ap` is truly a running Word.Application object. I recommend you set up a new project without all the "helper" your current project apparently has to test the basic object model code, then look for the "disconnect" in the current project

Comment: I cannot understand what you advise me to do. For example as you see my `getActiveObject()`, how do you recommend me to get the "real" object? Btw, my libs:  `using WordApi = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;`

Comment: OK, that `using` helps :-) Then the line is doing what it should do. I'm need to think some more...

Comment: In the question, you say "it doesn't work", but you don't describe exactly *how* it doesn't work. What does `result` return? Always `false`? Try a new WinForms project, with one button, that simply gets the Word.Application,  and tests Print Preview. Nothing fancy. My test - that worked - looked like this, for example: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { `WordApi.Application ap =(WordApi.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");Debug.Print(ap.PrintPreview.ToString());}`

Answer (score -2):

When the `Print Preview` window is displayed in Office applications, ribbon built-in controls are going to be hidden under the print preview window (or just disabled in some scenarios), i.e. the Backstage UI is shown. So, you can find any built-in control on the ribbon and check its [Enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarcontrol.enabled) and/or [Visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarcontrol.visible) property.

For example, the following VBA code checks whether a control is visible at any point of time:

```
Public Sub test()
 MsgBox Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("New").Visible
End Sub
```

When the `Print Preview` page is opened, you will not find such command bars, controls or they can be disabled or hidden simply.

This approach is described in depth in the [How to check programmatically if the user is editing an Excel cell](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/03/23/excel-check-user-edit-cell/) article. It is related to Excel, but the approach can be applied to any Office application.

Comment: Unfortunately, Print Preview window does not affect neither Enabled nor Visible property of the Ribbon. But the idea was good. Do you have any other?

Comment: You are on the wrong avenue. When you go to the Print section the Backstage UI is opened and the ribbon is hidden. Which control did you try to use for checking the `Visible` and `Enabled` properties?

Comment: `ap.CommandBars["Ribbon"].Enabled` or `ap.CommandBars["Ribbon"].Visible`

Comment: There is no control on the ribbon with idMso `Ribbon`.

Comment: Could you please tell me in more details what to do in my case? I appreciate your approach

Comment: Please review the article mentioned in my post. It provides the sample code.

Comment: I tried everything you provide. It really does not work to my project and I cannot understand why. Thanks although

Comment: I have added the sequence of property and method calls to get the value. What do you mean `does not work`? Do you get any exceptions?